# Android: Maps v2: draw a scalable circle around a marker

Tags: android, google-maps, geometry, google-maps-api-2, marker

I've run into a very tricky problem with Google Maps APIv2 : I want to draw a circle around a marker (nothing diffucult so far) but the cirle' radius must scaled according with the zoom level, so the marker's size and the circle's always maintain the same proportion.

I tryed to accomplish that doing calculations involving the current zoom level, the max and min zoom level and also the marker's icon size, but it turned out (from my calculations at least) that the way Maps increase/decrease the zoom level according to user interaction is not linear (I think it's somehow exponential).

anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

```
                                     **UPDATE**
```

A partial solution is available as an answer, you're welcome to suggest improvements

Comment: [If you check the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Circle) the radius is in metters, and it already changes (during zoom) to fit pixels to metters conversion.... so a 500 metters in max zoom has x pixels, but in minimum zoom, has y pixels

Comment: yes but i want to change the radius of the circle! 
I want the circle to be always around the marker, so when the user zoom out I want to change the radius accordingly since the marker will "cover" a bigger area of the map as the zoom decreases

Comment: [Then please check here for conversion rates](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to)

Comment: Thank you @bonatti, but i don't really get how to use this, are those meters per pixel? I think I'll have to convert them according to my device's resolution right?

Comment: You could convert them using the device resoulion, OR use the [viewport (by MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), and be independant of visualizations... Also, remember that DPI is not qual to pixel in devices.

Answer (score 0):

I've produced a partial solution:

- I take the BoundingBox currently visible on the map
- get the distance between the corners of one of the sides
- get the map size in pixels
- calculate the amount of meters per pixel
- multiply this value for the size of the marker icon

Unfortunatly, it works well only for zoom levels >5.5. This is caused by the distance calculation, which gives a different result according to the position of the camera because of the spherical shape of the earth.

Here's the code if someone have some idea how to improve it:

```
public double getRadius(){
        mapWidth = (double) mapFragment.getView().getWidth();
        LatLngBounds bb = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

        double distance = distance((bb.northeast.latitude - bb.southwest.latitude)/2, bb.northeast.longitude, (bb.northeast.latitude - bb.southwest.latitude)/2, bb.southwest.longitude);
        double metersPerPixel = distance / mapWidth;
        return 70*metersPerPixel;
    }

    private static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        dist = (dist * 1.609344)*1000;

        return (dist);
    }

    private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
```

code for calculating the distance found [here](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/java)

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment because of my reputation, but you should try to use a zoomChangeListener, i find this in other question..

> Create an implementation of `OnCameraChangeListener`, and pass an
>   instance of it to `setOnCameraChangeListener()` of your GoogleMap. Your
>   listener should be called with `onCameraChange()` whenever the user
>   changes the zoom, center, or tilt. You find out the new zoom level
>   from the CameraPosition object that you are passed.

And every time it happens you need to:

1. ClearTheMap
2. Set the marker again
3. Read the zoomLevel
4. Draw the circle according to the zoom level

You just have to make the math work for different zooms.

```
public OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener()
{
    new OnCameraChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) 
        {
            googleMap.clear();
            setMarkers();
            float actualZoom = position.zoom;
            drawCircle(actualZoom);
    }
};
}
```

Comment: The problem is not to retrieve the zoom level but calculating the circle radius according to it